# How can I use multiple things to check in an else statement?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a machine learning program. So far, I have stored each of the 'learned' meanings in a text file in a list of all things that are attribute to that meaning. The text file is read by a python file that generates class objects that attribute the data in the text file to them. Then, in a master python file, the main prompt is where I am having trouble.

```
else:
    try:
        for obj in gc.get_objects():
            try:
                if isinstance(obj, LearnedClasses.learned):
                    if str(user.lower()) in obj.keys:
                        exec(obj.exstring)
                        chat()
                        break
            except:
                raise Exception

    except Exception:
        user = user.split()
        for x in user:
            learnlist.append(x)
            learnch = random.choice(learnlist)
            learnp = input("What does '{}' mean?".format(learnch))
            learn(learnch, learnp)

chat()
```

This code is what follows the basic 'built-in' responses that I made. This is what happens after it can not find any keywords in the built-in section. I am using GC to collect all of the class objects that were generated from the text file. Then, if the prompt matches any keywords with any of its 'learned' keywords, I intend for it to respond with the responses set for that class. However, I can not get it to move on to the if ALL ELSE fails part, which starts at except Exception. How could I arrange this so that it can do what I described? Thank you.

Comment: Put this into a function.  Run through the for loop through all of your words.  If you get a match then do what you need to do and return.  After the for loop finishes, you know you have no matches.  So there you can do your if all else fails code because you know that you couldn't get there with a match because any match would have generated a return.  Basically, put this code into it's own function and change the break to a return.

Comment: Exceptions should be reserved for error handling, rather than serving the purpose of an `else` statement. You could try storing whether or not a match has been found in a variable instead.

Comment: Its better if you dont nest `try` blocks. You should also not use `try` - `except` as `if-else`. The `except` block will run only if there is an exception in the `try` block. You can trigger the exception. Can you check if the `raise Exception` is called? Add a print statement in the same except block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to follow this code; a couple of suggestions for improvement:

- `raise Exception` has a typo: it should be `raise Exception()`
- There's not much point having an `except` block which just raises an exception with no additional information; omit it?
- The garbage collector is not a good place to store information that you will, in fact, need later; can you change the code so that the learned classes are stored in a list in a variable, which is returned or passed around somehow?

  As a general rule, you should never touch the garbage collector unless you're running out of memory, and then only to figure out how to help it discard things.
- As others have suggested in the comments, rather than try/except, use something like a flag variable to keep track of whether you've already answered, or the for/break/else construct:

  ```py
  for lc in learned_class_list:
      if str(user.lower()) in lc.keys:
          exec(lc.exstring)
          chat()
          break
  else:
      user = user.split()
      for x in user:
          learnlist.append(x)
          learnch = random.choice(learnlist)
          learnp = input("What does '{}' mean?".format(learnch))
          learn(learnch, learnp)
  ```

Comment: I was able to retain my use of gc but your answer brought me to the realization that I can, in fact, use the for loop on its own as a conditional, as it will return false if nothing fits in any of the iterations. Thank you! Why must GC not be used until the circumstances you pointed out?

Comment: As the name suggests, the garbage collector is intended for, well, garbage... It's also sensitive to non-obvious changes in the rest of the program; some garbage is collected immediately, so you'll never see it in `gc.get_objects()`; some is collected periodically, so you may or may not see it depending on whether it's been collected already. You might move a piece of code into a function and find that the objects are now being collected too soon; or you might find that you're getting objects that you never intended to include. Having a list in a variable makes sure you get what you intend.